# OSGI Integration test in karaf container

Tags: java, maven, osgi, integration-testing, karaf

I am new to Karaf IT testing within the karaf container. I created a small practice project
[Practice OSGI project](https://github.com/jayeshgarg/OSGiPractice). All the bundles are running fine as I am able to run them in karaf container(3.0.8) and able to make a rest hit to manually test it out. But Now I am trying to test it via integration tests. I wrote a testcase as well, but when I try to execute it, the maven says, no tests to build. Here my objective is to run a simple command like `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean test` so that it builds the complete project and in end test it using integration test(deploy karaf container, deploy bundles and execute the test cases, and bring the container down).

I hope I am able to explain my objective and question well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try debugging using mvn -X .

Comment: @PratikAmbani I already tried that, but that was not helpful at that time. Anyways thanks a lot for trying to help me. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is in the wrong directory. It is in `src/test/main/java` while it should be in `src/test/java`.

After this change the test runs but produces an exception. So there is more to fix but I guess this already helps you a bit.

Btw. I saw that your maven projects all have version 0.1 this is not a good idea in maven. You should always use a SNAPSHOT version. Release version should only be built and deployed once as they can not be overwritten in a remote maven repo.

Comment: That folder issue did solved my problem of not picking up the ITCase file for execution. Also I updated the project version as per your suggestion. Thanks a lot. But now I am facing some issues which I am trying to solve. Incase I am unable to, I'll get back here.

Comment: I did some corrections in IT module and it started to work, but only a little bit. As first of all, the entire suite is running 2 times, secondly, the default log file is not having enough details about whats going on in the background(how can I fix that?). Thirdly and finally, there are some errors are shown at the time of `mvn clean install`. I am doubtful if the TCs are running successfully. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting your answer as it broke my deadlock in writing IT cases.

Comment: I got your test working and did a pull request on your repo.

Comment: I also got it working... w.ll surly check your code as well... Thanks for the pull request. I have also updated my code (my way) in the repo. Please do take a look as and when you are free... do provide your inputs.

Comment: Your feedback regarding putting dependencies in parent, that I did as I was unsure where I did wrong. Now since everything is working, I'll be optimizing it for sure. Thanks for your valuable feedback.